# Azure function Application Insights unable to capture logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a Azure function behind private end point. The Application Insights associated with this Azure function is unable to capture logs.The transaction search in the App Insights gives the below error message

AI: Diagnostic message: backoff logic was enabled. Backoff internal exceeded 60 min. Did anyone face similar issue.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

- I understand that some of the logs data from your Azure Functions is not captured by the Application Insights and showing the `backoff internal exceeded 60 min` in the diagnostic message.
- There is a retry mechanism in the Azure Functions - Application Insights SDK for specifically solving the issues of data loss, Events missed and Application health monitoring.
- Some of the Azure Functions provides with the built-in retry mechanism, retry policies with that individual function runtime.
- Whatever the Runtime Stack of Azure Functions integrated with the Application Insights, there are retry mechanisms provided by Microsoft for resolving the production issues of data (logs) missing from the Event based triggers.

**Reference**: [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay,in-process&pivots=programming-language-powershell#retry-policies-preview) on Retry Mechanism Implementation.